# React-Native: Crash on Android 10 and 9 (API 28 and 29) dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, google-play, android-10.0

So, recently I have updated my react-native application from using the framework's 0.59 version to using 0.63. Things went smoothly until I noticed that after I uploaded my new .AAB file on Google Play, a percentage of my users (about 10%) started to get this error "dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass".

After investigating, I found out that it only happens on some (not all) devices that have API level 28 or 29, as shown on this dashboard:

[Google Play Error Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDoRv.png)

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:4268)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:270)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2067)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7948)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService (AppComponentFactory.java:129)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService (CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService (ActivityThread.java:4263)
```

I have searched the internet for solutions, and tried a few of them, but had no luck fixing it. Some said it was related to MultiDex support, but I have enabled it a long time ago:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And also:

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

I would be really grateful if someone could shine some light on what the problem could be. Here is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.12.0",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.2",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.7",
        "@react-native-community/picker": "1.7.1",
        "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.5.0",
        "EventEmitter": "1.0.0",
        "aws-sdk": "2.757.0",
        "axios": "0.18.0",
        "blueimp-md5": "^2.10.0",
        "firebase": "6.2.4",
        "firebase-key": "2.0.2",
        "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "4.17.5",
        "mobx": "3.1.10",
        "mobx-react": "4.2.1",
        "mobx-remotedev": "0.2.8",
        "mobx-utils": "2.0.2",
        "moment": "^2.19.0",
        "native-base": "2.13.14",
        "ramda": "0.24.1",
        "react": "16.13.1",
        "react-native": "0.63.3",
        "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
        "react-native-build-config": "0.3.2",
        "react-native-camera": "3.40.0",
        "react-native-code-push": "6.3.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "6.0.2",
        "react-native-document-picker": "2.3.0",
        "react-native-fbsdk": "2.0.0",
        "react-native-file-viewer": "2.1.4",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
        "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.12",
        "react-native-masked-text": "^1.5.3",
        "react-native-mime-types": "^2.3.0",
        "react-native-push-notification": "5.1.1",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
        "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "7.1.0",
        "react-native-webview": "10.9.0",
        "react-navigation": "4.4.1",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "2.5.1",
        "react-navigation-stack": "2.8.3",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "2.9.1",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "0.12.0",
        "uuid": "3.1.0",
        "validator": "^9.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-flow": "7.0.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
        "@types/prop-types": "15.7.1",
        "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
        "eslint": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-reactnative": "^1.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.11.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.1",
        "flow-bin": "^0.65.0",
        "grpc": "1.21.1",
        "jest": "^25.1.0",
        "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and in my case, it was a class missing.

If you have a chance, get a device with error and when the Send feedback modal pops up, click into Preview button, scroll down and then select 'Stack trace'.

It works for me to find out what class was missing.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to fix this error by updating our `zo0r/react-native-push-notification` dependency and migrating from using deprecated GCM notification format (which Amazon SNS still theoretically supported, but the new version of zo0r/react-native-push-notification didn't) to FCM format.

After those changes, the errors stopped appearing on Google Play Console.